# Diagnosing Slow Initial Load

Tags: joomla, web, performance-testing, pagespeed, rackspace

How do you go about diagnosing a website that initially loads slowly? That is, it is unresponsive for up to 10 seconds, and then loads quickly after that.

You can see the loading chart here: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/130128_XV_GVN/3/details/

I know that "something" is slowing it down, but I can't tell what. Is there any way of knowing what is causing the delay?

EDIT: Here are the values from Joomla's debug mode:

```
Application 0.013 seconds (+0.013); 1.33 MB (+1.327) - afterLoad
Application 0.783 seconds (+0.770); 9.53 MB (+8.199) - afterInitialise
Application 0.952 seconds (+0.169); 11.00 MB (+1.473) - afterRoute
Application 1.164 seconds (+0.212); 12.76 MB (+1.758) - afterDispatch
Application 2.453 seconds (+1.289); 19.04 MB (+6.287) - beforeRenderModule mod_roknavmenu ()
Application 2.858 seconds (+0.405); 20.91 MB (+1.865) - afterRenderModule mod_roknavmenu ()
Application 2.977 seconds (+0.119); 20.98 MB (+0.075) - beforeRenderModule mod_login (Member Access)
Application 3.012 seconds (+0.035); 21.09 MB (+0.102) - afterRenderModule mod_login (Member Access)
Application 3.019 seconds (+0.008); 21.09 MB (-0.000) - beforeRenderModule mod_hot_joomla_carousel (Front Page Carousel)
Application 3.033 seconds (+0.014); 21.13 MB (+0.040) - afterRenderModule mod_hot_joomla_carousel (Front Page Carousel)
Application 3.057 seconds (+0.024); 21.12 MB (-0.010) - beforeRenderModule mod_rokgallery (FP RokGallery)
Application 3.793 seconds (+0.736); 29.68 MB (+8.570) - afterRenderModule mod_rokgallery (FP RokGallery)
Application 3.847 seconds (+0.053); 29.64 MB (-0.048) - afterRender
```

Comment: Was this a migrated site? Also what component/view are you loading on that page?

Comment: Yes, I built it on a separate domain, and then exported it with Akeeba backup before restoring it on this domain.

The site is built with the Gantry framework. I've simply created a home page override and placed modules into it. I'm unsure of how that fits into Joomla's MVC framework...

Comment: What do you mean "a bhome page override"?  What is the default menu link?

Comment: Gantry describes it here: http://www.gantry-framework.org/documentation/joomla/configure/template-overrides

The default menu link is: index.php?option=com_content&view=featured

Comment: So this was never a 1.5 site?
How many featured articles do you have?
What version of MySQL are you running?
To test the Gantry is slow theory switch to one of the default templates and see if it loads faster.

Comment: It was a 1.7 site until it was upgraded to 2.5. Regarding MySQL, I noticed this message when I went to check its version: Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.77 differs from your MySQL server version 5.1.61. This may cause unpredictable behavior. This may have been a result of moving it from an server that was running an older version. Could this be related? It can't be a "Gantry being slow" problem because the load time is fine on my test site http://brideaus.thirdcore.com (except the images taking a while because they weren't optimized).

Comment: Yes I bet that is the culprit, recently on one of the development lists there was a big discussion of MySQL version and performance. Try getting that straightened out and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable Rok modules and plugins. Check if that changes anything. If you're using memcached caching try to disable it or eventually change to Files. Even you have slow disk Files caching can improve the site. Memcached sometimes give opposite results to what is expected.

Also try to find out if your issues are related to CloudFlare service you're using. Just crate a subdomain going directly to your back end hosting and see if response time is different.

If nothing helps and you don't see issues in Joomla debug output then it's time for server side debug. I assume you're using linux hosting. Find out if dns resolving works good on your server. Just use ping, dig or host to query any domain name for IP address. If you see a pause for name resolution then fix your resolver first.

If you're running php with CGI then you can try [stracing](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) php proces and find out if it makes pauses on something eg. waiting for connection to db maybe?
Other way is to employ [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) php module and do function tracing. You can use xdebug either you run php as CGI or server module.

Answer (score 0):

I would put it down to the host and/or the heavy template + additional extensions you're running. I have always found Rockettheme templates and their framework extremely heavy due to the number and size of JavaScript and CSS files.

What you could do is, take a backup of the website and run it on a localhost such as [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en), to see if there is any difference in the load speed.

If you see the site running much faster, you might want to consider a different host. If there is not much difference then I think a different template might be needed.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above comments any template based on a framework is usually slow, to see if this is the issue simply assign the beez menu to the homepage and see how much of a difference it makes.

Usually a time so high means you have your cache not properly configured, and / or many modules on the homepage which aren't optimized, and / or a massive number of articles.  There are solutions to all of these, but please do a few tests so we can nail down the main issues.

It's best if you work on a non-live copy so you can play with it without disrupting the current site.

1. put the site in debug mode (from the global configuration) and
   reload the homepage. You should see a table below the page with
   loading times.  Save them.
2. assign another template, create the right module positions so it will load the same content as your current home.  Save the time it took to load
3. verify that your cache plugin is enabled and that your cache is enabled in the configuration with an appropriate timing*. Clear the cache then do a timed page load (save the times) and then immediately reload the page.  By comparing the two times we'll hopefully learn which is the offending extension or issue.

This is just some basic diagnostics, once you post back we could go a bit further.

- appropriate cache timing: if you get 2 hits / hour, and your cache is set to the default 15 minutes, you're not using the cache at all!!! If you're getting 400 hits/ hour then only 4 will be used to generate the cache i.e. 1% of requests will be slower.  The lower your hits, the higher the cache time should be to make it effective.

Comment: Hey Riccardo, I think we can toss out the 'templates are slow' hypothesis, as the time-to-first-byte for the development environment is just fine: http://thirdcore.brideaus.com/ I've attached the debug output to the original post above, and have enabled the cache plugin and made the changes you recommended, but am still seeing the same results.

Comment: It's definitely slow! You can seee that the 4 modules mentioned are _not_ using cache, and mod_rokgallery is using .75 seconds and 8.5 Mb of RAM, for a total of 29. Now I don't know what your component shows, but I'm working on a heavy site that has been hardly optimized with jomsocial and joomlistings (two massive components), and on a search result page, with 114 queries, google maps, a ton of jquery plugins, takes 4mb all inclusive and .850 seconds.  There must be a misconfiguration of the rokgallery and the main component at least. How many articles do you have / how many featured?

Answer (score -1):

Your issue sounds like a TTFB(time to First Byte) issue and is possibly directly related to heavy DB queries, slow host performance, heavy page rendering, that all lead to long response time from the server.

I agree to the comments above, first check the performance on a locally installed server (i use here WAMP server). You can also hack a bit into the joomla framework and enhance the functionality of the debugging by adding additional info from component and plugin rendering.

For debugging components, you need to edit the file libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php and replace

```
$contents = self::executeComponent($path);
```

with

```
if (constant('JDEBUG')) {
JProfiler::getInstance('Application')->mark('beforeExecuteComponent ' . $option.' ('.$task.')');
}
$contents = self::executeComponent($path);
if (constant('JDEBUG')) {
JProfiler::getInstance('Application')->mark('afterExecuteComponent ' . $option.' ('.$task.')');
}
```

For plugins edit libraries/joomla/event/dispacher.php and replace

```
if (is_object($this->_observers[$key]))
{
$args['event'] = $event;
$value = $this->_observers[$key]->update($args);
}
// Fire the event for a function based observer.
elseif (is_array($this->_observers[$key]))
{
$value = call_user_func_array($this->_observers[$key]['handler'], $args);
}
```

with this:

```
if (constant('JDEBUG'))
{
$pluginName = '';
if (is_object($this->_observers[$key])) {
$pluginName = get_class($this->_observers[$key]);
}
JProfiler::getInstance('Application')->mark('Execute Plugin ' . $pluginName.'::'.$event.' - START');
}
// Fire the event for an object based observer.
if (is_object($this->_observers[$key]))
{
$args['event'] = $event;
$value = $this->_observers[$key]->update($args);
}
// Fire the event for a function based observer.
elseif (is_array($this->_observers[$key]))
{
$value = call_user_func_array($this->_observers[$key]['handler'], $args);
}
if (constant('JDEBUG'))
{
JProfiler::getInstance('Application')->mark('Execute Plugin ' . $pluginName.'::'.$event.' - END');
}
```

Now you can examine, in which order the plugins, modules are loaded and how long each load takes.